# Recognition the same object from different views

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, image-processing, caffe

I have 33 classes (33 different objects). I need to recognize the object from any view of the object. Like a packet of potato chips, the packet has different appearance from different view (as shown in the attached images).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I trained those images as one class even though they have different appearance.
Then I do augmentation to have different rotation and add in noises. So one object has about 600 images to train.

I have 33 classes to train and all classes are taken from different views.
So I have about 20,000 images to train.

When I train with [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd), detection is very poor.
Currently I am training with Faster-RCNN, still training and I notice that loss is not converging well.

How should I improve the detection?
Is that ok to train as one class for different views of the object?

Should I separate images in different views and train different models for different views?